# Should i make simple this logo?

Tags: logo, images

im making this logo for a Restaurant in a little town in Peru called Lobitos. They want to look friendly because their service is one of their most important strength. Should i make it simpler? Like one basic shape o a simpler shape? Greetings!

[image]

After the answer of go-meek i've made the following changes. Tell me what you think and thank you very much it really helps me a lot!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE, Teibol! If you have any questions about how the site works, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I see a face in the three birds and sun (once seen, never to be unseen) so I'd lose the birds. I'm also unsure what the palm is adding so I'd lose that too. At tiny sizes I'd make the roundel white. All that said, I think it's charming! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wonder if the logo is too complex, try looking at it at different sizes.

This logo sample at very small size might not show clearly a lot of the details! For example, try looking at this logo at 1 inch or 2 centimeters width to see how it looks. Then work on making sure the main subject of it is clear and has lot of contrast. In this logo, I guess you want the woman to be the central point.

One way you could add more emphasis on the woman in the logo is by making her stand out a bit out of the circle frame. It could add some dynamism as if she's growing out of the frame and she'll be bigger too. Nothing stops you from keeping the beach landscape in the circle and it will look secondary if you make the woman stand out.

The other part is contrast. Will your logo look good too in grayscale? I think the one you posted will probably have the same kind of gray once in grayscale. The background might engulf the main subject. Try making a version in black and white to see if the concept works well or can be done this way; the restaurant will certainly need a one-color logo version for their paperwork or for photocopies.

I like the size of the text, the position, the colors and the font style you chose. It's very friendly. You can increase the size of the text a bit if you want; you will see if it needs to be bigger when you'll look at i at small size. The person who asked you for that logo might require it anyway. Maybe wrap it bigger around the woman illustration that will come out of the circle frame.

Comment: thanks! your answer was really helpful for me...i've made the changes but dont know how to show you the result!

Comment: @Teibol Glad it helped! You can always edit your question and add the result as an update if you want :)

Comment: @Teibol It looks great! I like how you placed the woman with the elbow and tray out of the frame, it's even better than what I had in mind when I wrote my answer!